# How to remove question marks from attributes in a Rails validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

```
validates :tag, format: { with: /[^?]+/, message:'cannot have question marks') }
```

I want the validation to fail for this value:

```
tag = "why not?"
```

and pass for this one:

```
tag = "why not"
```

I don't understand how to simply chomp the '?' in the string with regex.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your validation like this:

```
validates :tag, format: { without: /\?/, message: 'cannot have question marks' }
```

Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of

Comment: awesome thanks, I didnt see that i could do :without

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if you think it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove **all** the `?` in your string, simple do: `"why not?".gsub("?", '')`

**Edit**
I just re-read your question and you wanted regex for your validations (ugh, i need coffee).

You need to escape the `?` because `?` in regex means *zero of one of a...* so just change your validation to -> `validates :tag, format: { with: /\?/, message:'cannot  question marks') }`